# What does range full operator do in borsh serialize?

Tags: account, deserialization, borsh, serialization, iter

I follow [hackernoon-solana](https://hackernoon.com/an-introduction-to-building-on-the-solana-network) to see the syntax in non anchor project. this is the function signature

```
pub fn process_instruction(program_id:&Pubkey,accounts:&[AccountInfo],input:&[u8])->ProgramResult{}
```

we pass `accounts:&[AccountInfo]` array as an arg. Args are always byte array

```
// Iterating accounts is safer then indexing
let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
```

Then I get the first account

```
let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
```

then deserialize the passed arg. in rust arguments are an array of bytes

```
 let mut greeting_account = GreetingAccount::try_from_slice(&account.data.borrow())?;
```

So far so good. but I did not understand this line:

```
 greeting_account.serialize(&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
```

We are storing the data inside `greeting_account`. BUt what is this `[..]` for? `account` is a single object, how can we use a range operator on an object?

Answer (score 2):

That's just another way of dereferencing to get the internal data in Rust. `&mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..]` and `*account_info.data.borrow_mut()` should get the same result. You could write that line as:

```
greeting_account.serialize(&mut *account.data.borrow_mut())?;
```

Comment: This is correct, but in general, please use the `to_writer` helper to avoid issues trashing the underlying slice. See https://github.com/near/borsh-rs/pull/34 for more info